# Confirm Ubuntu updates

Tags: ubuntu, security, updates, verification

Over the past couple of weeks I've noticed that my Ubuntu 11.10 installation has had many security related updates, including changes to CA Certificates.

Is there Ubuntu web page that lists all updates valid updates and a summary of the changes?

Comment: See [Latest updates with changelog for oneiric](http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/packages/latest_logs?utf8=%E2%9C%93&dist=oneiric&commit=Go&noppa=2)

Answer (score 0):

In terms of security, the update process is pretty secure because of GPG signatures. Your machine has a GPG keyring with trusted keys for package archives (`apt-key list` will show these), and `apt-get`/`aptitude` uses these to verify the `Release` file (which is then the root of a chain of SHA256 hashes which ultimately verify the downloaded .deb file). You do need to be careful of additional repositories like Launchpad PPAs which you configure though.

http://packages.ubuntu.com/ is an online database of the official Ubuntu archives, which can be used to determine the latest version of packages (e.g. [ca-certificates](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/ca-certificates)) and the package [changelog](http://changelogs.ubuntu.com/changelogs/pool/main/c/ca-certificates/ca-certificates_20111211/changelog). It isn't accessible over HTTPS unfortunately, so I wouldn't trust it for security purposes. The [ubuntu-security-announce](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-security-announce/) mailing list contains announcements of changes to the security archive (these messages can be verified with GPG if you subscribe to the list).